# Неоднородные согласованные определения, одно из которых распространено: пунктуация

Tags: пунктуация, определения, однородные-неоднородные-определения

- **Мы встретились на забитом товарами шумном складе.**
- **Мы встретились на шумном, забитом товарами складе.**

Во втором случае прямо просится запятая, хотя определения как были согласованные и неоднородные, так и остались.
Почему? Вероятно, я не знаю какое-то правило, касающееся распространённых определений?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Считаю, что здесь используется вот это правило Розенталя.

**1.** Между однородными определениями, не связанными союзами, ставится **запятая**.
Согласованные определения являются однородными:
7) если за одиночным определением следует определение, выраженное причастным оборотом: *малоизвестные, расположенные на отшибе курганы; древняя, почерневшая от времени деревянная статуэтка; небольшое, устланное коврами возвышение; чёрные, гладко причёсанные волосы; худое, изборождённое глубокими морщинами лицо; пустое; запорошенное снегом поле; ранняя, чуть заигравшая зорька; твёрдый, плохо выбритый подбородок* (ср. при другом порядке слов: *плохо выбритый твёрдый подбородок*).

Ставится только **одна** запятая.
**На шумном, тускло освещённом** Шереметьевском аэродроме, полном голодных костлявых солдатиков, никто не встретил его. [Ирина Муравьева. Мещанин во дворянстве (1994)]
Все чаще мне становится жаль, что я живу **в огромном, забитом до отказа машинами** мегаполисе. [Дарья Донцова. Уха из золотой рыбки (2004)]
**В небольшом, забитом сеном** сарае было свежо и тихо. [А. П. Гайдар. Школа (1929)]

Хотя случаи обособления причастного оборота встречаются.
Есть еще пароходная свистулька над бараком, приспособленная вместо радиоантенны, градусник, прибитый высоко над окошком, чтоб не достали ребятишки, обломок якоря, подвешенный **ко второй, забитой для тепла,** двери барака, в сердечко которого бьют, если пожар, или на собрание надо, или кто заблудился в тундре... [Виктор Астафьев. Царь-рыба (1974)]

[Однородные и неоднородные определения](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=98#pp98)

Comment: Спасибо. Моя ошибка в том, что я не распознал в 'забитом' причастия.

Comment: А что-нибудь изменится, если на месте причастия будет прилагательное? И почему вообще происходит такая трансформация определений: были неоднородные, а стали однородными . Есть ли в правилах пояснение на эту тему? (Извините, адрес я не пишу, так как обращаюсь ко всем участникам темы.) Можно было бы задать вопрос на форуме, но никто там отвечать не будет, да и здесь вряд ли захотят ответить.  Нестандартное в круг интересов обычно не входит. Наверное, это психологическая особенность людей:  нам нравится все знакомое, узнаваемое, привычное, но совсем не хочется идти вглубь неизвестного.

Comment: @Sharon неоднородность определений — тема вообще не всегда внятная. Чего стоит, скажем, разное восприятие в разных стилях речи (Розенталь: *В зависимости от стиля речи некоторые примеры допускают разное понимание, а в связи с этим — разную интонацию и пунктуацию; ср.: **Именно эти новые, большие, многоэтажные здания в основном определяли лицо города** (Кат.) — в художественной прозе; **Построены новые большие многоэтажные дома** — в деловой речи)*. // А как вы прицепите к прилагательному зависимое слово, чтобы смысл вопроса остался?

Comment: @Sharon *я встретился с красным от жары ушлым господином...* *Я встретился с ушлым(,) красным от жары господином...* Мне кажется, тут не просится запятая. Наоборот, её постановка заставляет мозг судорожно искать, в чём же однородность между ушлостью и краснотой от жары... Нет у вас такого ощущения?

Comment: Мне эти примеры понятны, а тема называется сближение признаков. По сути определения неоднородные, но будут считаться однородными, если создают ЕДИНЫЙ ОБРАЗ, раскрывают одну тему. Во втором примере запятая  обязана быть (ее редко не ставят), поэтому вы ее напишите.  Почему? Для оборота и единичного определения важен взаимный ПОРЯДОК СЛОВ. А вот почему важен – это тайна, но я ее случайно знаю (шутка). Спросите у ваших собеседников, я бы тоже послушала.  Вас они любят, и всё вам расскажут :)

Comment: @Sharon не думал, что "Должна быть в женщине какая-то загадка, Должна быть тайна в ней какая-то" — это про вас и порядок слов)

Comment: Ну да, я умею читать у Розенталя то, что написано между строк бесцветными чернилами.  Ну это так, для примера :)

Comment: @sharon проблема невидимых чернил в том, что они могут быть исключительно в воображении читающего.

Comment: Что ж, тогда будем думать, что они только в моем воображении.  Ну а вы читайте то, что написано чернилами обычными. Только вот что интересно: правила Розенталя доступны всем, но почему возникает так много неясных вопросов у наших пользователей? Может быть, там не все написано? Пожалуй, да, факультативные решения он практически не рассматривает,  пояснения дает в отдельных случаях…

Answer (score 1):

***Мы встретились на шумном, забитом товарами складе.***

> Согласованные определения являются **однородными:**
> <...>
> 7) если за одиночным определением следует определение, выраженное причастным оборотом: *малоизвестные, расположенные на отшибе курганы; древняя, почерневшая от времени деревянная статуэтка*...

[**Однородные и неоднородные определения**](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=98) (Розенталь).

Comment: Спасибо. Римма Михайлова чуть раньше ответила, поэтому её ответ принял, но вы указали на ту же мою ошибку: я почему-то не понял, что а данном случае 'забитый' — причастие, а не прилагательное.

Comment: Спасибо и вам за вопрос!